# Computing the homology of the torus with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$, using two methods

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have some trouble to compute the homology of the torus with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$ for $p$ a prime number. In particular I have a problem for $H_1$ :

1) The first way to compute it is to use the UCT
$$H_1(S^1 \times S^1, \Bbb F_p) = H_1(S^1 \times S^1) \otimes \Bbb F_p \;\oplus\; \text{Tor}(H_0(S^1\times S^1); \Bbb F_p)\\
=\Bbb F_p ^2 \oplus \text{Tor}(\Bbb Z; \Bbb F_p) = \Bbb F_p ^2$$

2) The second way is to use the fact that $\Bbb F_p \otimes \Bbb F_p = \Bbb F_p$ so that
$$H_1(S^1 \times S^1, \Bbb F_p) = 
H_1(C'_*(S^1, \Bbb F_p) \otimes C'_*(S^1, \Bbb F_p))
\\\cong 
 \bigoplus_{r+s=1} H_r( S^1 ,\Bbb F_p) \otimes H_{s}( S^1 ,\Bbb F_p) \oplus \bigoplus_{r+s=0} \text{Tor}(H_r( S^1 ,\Bbb F_p) ; H_{s}( S^1 ,\Bbb F_p))
\\=
H_0 \otimes H_1  \;\oplus\; H_1 \otimes H_0 \;\oplus\; \text{Tor}(H_0,H_0) \\=
\Bbb F_p \otimes \Bbb F_p  \;\oplus\; \Bbb F_p \otimes \Bbb F_p  \;\oplus\; \Bbb F_p = \Bbb F_p^3 $$
where $C'_*(E,A) := C_*(E) \otimes A$, $C_*(E)=$ set of singular chains in $E$, and $A$ any abelian group.
Here I used Eilenberg-Zilber and Künneth theorems.

Here is my question:

> Why do I find $\Bbb F_p^2$ with the first method, and $\Bbb F_p^3$ with the second one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the Kunneth theorem, the Tor is being taken over $\mathbb{F}_p$, not over $\mathbb{Z}$, and so it vanishes. Over a field the Kunneth theorem just says that the homology of a product is a graded tensor product of homologies.

The assumption that $p > 3$ does not help you in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, but in the first line of 2) : $$H_1(\;C'_*(S^1, \Bbb F_p) \otimes C'_*(S^1, \Bbb F_p)\;)$$ I take the homology with coefficients in the integers. So then I should apply Künneth with $\text{Tor}_1^{\Bbb Z}$, in my opinion.

Comment: @Watson: the version of the Kunneth theorem I assume you're using (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem#Singular_homology_with_coefficients_in_a_principal_ideal_domain) computes homology with coefficients in a PID $R$ in terms of Tor over $R$. Here $R = \mathbb{F}_p$.